# How do I optimize images like Facebook and WhatsApp in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-optimization

I want optimize images like Facebook and WhatsApp in my website.all user are uploading in hign memory size ..so it take more time to load my that page..

Comment: If you show these images in a gallery-style like Facebook, crop them on back-end and show that specific cropped image during gallery-style preview and load the hi-res image only when a user clicks on any of those images.

Comment: That depends on your back-end stack, you've only tagged your front-end technologies. If it's PHP you have Imagick for example.